# Why doesn't this 'usergrouplist' field show a label?

Tags: user-groups, fields, component-configuration

To elaborate:
The component's configuration is supposed to show a field where i choose which usergroup gets access to a certain view. The fieldtype used is 'usergrouplist'. I've also tried 'usergroups' previously(only to end up at the same result).

I've check the same thing is there in com_users but it shows a label while mine doesn't.

**How do I get this field to show a label?**

*The code:*

```
<fieldset
    name="permissions"
    label="COM_PLACEHOLDER_DICTIONARY_PERMISSIONS"
    description="COM_PLACEHOLDER_CONFIG_DESC_PERMS"
>
    <field name="view_access" type="usergrouplist"
        label="COM_PLACEHOLDER_CONFIG_VIEWACCESS_LABEL"
        description="COM_PLACEHOLDER_CONFIG_VIEWACCESS_DESC"
        default="1" checksuperusergroup="1"/>
</fieldset>
```

*Notice how it doesn't show a 'Label' for the field.*

[image: Notice how the 'label' part of the field isn't there]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after I uninstalled and reinstalled the component. So apparently there's nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely in your view. What do you get when you print something like the following in your view?

```
<?php echo $this->form->getLabel('view_access'); ?>
```